# Access object context in override SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

So I want to keep track of the last change done to any of my objects, this last change is saved on the "head" object. I'll sketch it.

I have an object `Project` containing a list of `Activities`, which in turn has a list of `Actions` both with different properties and so on.
The `Project` has a property `LastUpdateDate` on which I want to keep the last update done on any property of the `Project` itself or any  of its 'subobjects'.

For this I override the `SaveChanges` method of the entity framework as follows:

```
public override int SaveChanges() {

var changedEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries();
if (changedEntries != null)
        {
            var dbEntityEntries = changedEntries as IList<DbEntityEntry> ?? changedEntries.ToList();
            foreach (var entry in dbEntityEntries.Where(c => c.State != EntityState.Unchanged))
            {
                var proj = entry.Entity as Project;
                if (proj != null)
                {
                    proj.LastUpdateDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                }

                var prop = entry.Entity as Activity;
                if (prop != null)
                {
                    var changedProject = dbEntityEntries.Single(x => (x.Entity is Project) && ((Project) x.Entity).Id == prop.ProjectId);
                    ((Project) changedProject.Entity).LastUpdateDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                }
            }
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

My dataset is larger and has more properties than in the example above, therefor I dont want to be looping through every entity because this will take up too much time.

In stead of this, I would like to access my `ObjectContext` so I can say for instance: `project[0].Activity[1]...`

Has anyone here got any idea on how to reach this situation?

Comment: You want to access `ObjectContext` from the `ObjectContext` method override? What difficulties you have?

Comment: I dont seem to be able to get to my object hierarchy. Only `entries` which I need to cast to a specific type and this way I need to loop too much. That why I'd like my object setup to be available as the actual objects.

Comment: What is "my object setup"? Could you update the question with a piece of pseudo-code, which you want to get?

Comment: "My object setup" is for instance: `var allActionsOnProjectZero = project[0].Activity[23].Actions;` So I can access my hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer the first part of this question: Here's how you access the ObjectContext:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    this.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
    var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var changedEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries();

    if (changedEntries != null)
    {
        var dbEntityEntries = changedEntries as IList<DbEntityEntry> ?? changedEntries.ToList();

        dbEntityEntries.Select(i=>i.Entity).OfType<Project>().Distinct()
            .Union(dbEntityEntries.Select(i=>i.Entity).OfType<Activity>().Select(activity=>activity.Project))
                .Union(dbEntityEntries.Select(i=>i.Entity).OfType<Action>().Select(action => action.Activity.Project))
        .Distinct().ToList()
        .ForEach(p => p.LastUpdateDate = DateTime.UtcNow);
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: How do I do this when I do not have my `Project` object on the `Activity` itself but only the `projectId`. Same goes for `Action` only having `activityId`?